# How to parse an object to JSON using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know to use `eval()` to parse JSON to an object, but how do I parse an object to JSON format using JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but you're going to have to be _a lot_ clearer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newer browsers support [`JSON.stringify`](http://www.json.org/js.html). You can also [download](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and include it yourself.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(yourObject);
```

Afaik jQuery does not provide such a method.

Comment: can JSON object easy to parse an json string to an object ?

Comment: It's not a simple task and I don't think jquery provides this. JSON is not supported in IE. http://www.json.org/json2.js will do what you need with JSON.stringify and JSON.parse. Ext-core has methods called Ext.encode and Ext decode which do the same thing http://www.sencha.com/products/core/docs/?class=Ext

Comment: @zjm1126: It don't know exactly what you mean, but `JSON` also provides the `JSON.parse` method. It is described on the site I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you have a json and want to access something underneath it you just put a dot, like if the name of your json is msg and you want the location parameter it would be:

msg.location